# Quercus: Java and PHP integration

Tags: java, php, quercus

I was try Quercus these days, I want to create a java PHP integration module, after looking at the tutorials, I was stack at the part below:

> Step 3: Create com.caucho.quercus.QuercusModule and place it in $webApp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services
>   example.HelloModule

BTW, the demo `http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/tutorial/module/hello.php` or `http://quercus.caucho.com/quercus-3.1/examples/quercus-module/hello.php` is not working as well.

Can somebody help me with this problem? Thank you.

**Reference:**
http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/tutorial/module/index.xtp
http://quercus.caucho.com/quercus-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#module

Comment: have you already tried PHP/Java extension: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.java.php ?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: Thanks, I have solved the problem, the step3 asks me to create a file named com.caucho.quercus.QuercusModule, which is not clear in the statement. :)

Comment: Post your answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Step 3: Create com.caucho.quercus.QuercusModule and place it in $webApp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services example.HelloModule

Means you need to create a file named com.caucho.quercus.QuercusModule and put it into $webApp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services folder, the content should be example.HelloModule.
The documentation is really not clear :(

Comment: It seems that at least from 4.0.44 onwards you have to put that file into $webApp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/quercus/ instead.